# How to stop sqlalchemy or pyodbc casting bigint to numeric when reflecting tables?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to reflect tables from a sql server database. One of the tables has an id column, type bigint and starts with the lower limit value, -9223372036854775808. I realized during the reflection, that I get a

```
DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('22003', '[22003] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting bigint to data type numeric. (8115) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

error which apparently it's trying to downconvert bigint to numeric. is there a way to prevent this? or give the precision I am looking for when converting to numeric?

I tried different ways:

1. auto reflecting all tables :

```
engine = create_engine(db connection)
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(autoload_with=engine)
```

also by creating the table:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy import BigInteger

metadata = MetaData()

# reflect the table
table = Table('OEData', metadata, autoload_with=engine)
```

and in both cases I get the same error shown  above.

I am using :

sqlalchemy 2.0.21

MS Sql server 2014

thanks

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://gist.github.com/gordthompson/098cd29347ab5a31f63431c557b90ae2) works fine for me.

Comment: @GordThompson, I have been able to get your code working, but not sure what's the issue with my table. Please look at comments from the code you shared. thanks

Comment: @GordThompson, I did realize this issue comes if I create the table with Identity.
e.g. ` id bigint IDENTITY(-9223372036854775808, 1) primary key` and your test code will fail too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have encountered a bug in SQLAlchemy's reflection code for mssql. It has been reported here

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/10504